# Improve Python + Influxdb import performance

Tags: python, performance, weblogic, jython, influxdb

The following script is an extract from

https://github.com/RittmanMead/obi-metrics-agent/blob/master/obi-metrics-agent.py

```
import calendar, time
import sys
import getopt
import httplib

print '---------------------------------------'

try:
    wls_user = "user"
    wls_pw = "pw"
    url  = "url"
    outputFormat="Influxdb"
    targetHost="hostname"
    targetPort="port"
    targetDB="dbname"
except:
    print ''

print wls_user, wls_pw,url, outputFormat,targetHost,targetPort,targetDB

now_epoch = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())*1000

influx_msgs=''
connect(wls_user,wls_pw,url)
results = displayMetricTables('Oracle_BI*','dms_cProcessInfo')
for table in results:
    tableName = table.get('Table')
    rows = table.get('Rows')
    rowCollection = rows.values()
    iter = rowCollection.iterator()
    while iter.hasNext():
        row = iter.next()
        rowType = row.getCompositeType()
        keys = rowType.keySet()
        keyIter = keys.iterator()
        inst_name= row.get('Name').replace(' ','-')
        try:
            server= row.get('Servername').replace(' ','-').replace('/','_')
        except:
            try:
                server= row.get('ServerName').replace(' ','-').replace('/','_')
            except:
                server='unknown'
        try:
            host= row.get('Host').replace(' ','-')
        except:
            host=''
        while keyIter.hasNext():
            columnName = keyIter.next()
            value = row.get(columnName )
            if columnName.find('.value')>0:
                metric_name=columnName.replace('.value','')
                if value is not None:
                    if value != 0:
                        if outputFormat=='InfluxDB':
                            influx_msg= ('%s,server=%s,host=%s,metric_group=%s,metric_instance=%s value=%s %s') % (metric_name,server,host,tableName,inst_name,  value,now_epoch*1000000)
                            influx_msgs+='\n%s' % influx_msg
                            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('%s:%s' % (targetHost,targetPort))
                            ## TODO pretty sure should be urlencoding this ...
                            a=conn.request("POST", ("/write?db=%s" % targetDB), influx_msg)
                            r=conn.getresponse()
```

Influxdb is currently loading data at around 5 points/second (total 1:45 min). 
Any way to improve performance?
Also I've attached a sample extract of the data

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaDOv.jpg)

**EDIT 1:**

I was given a suggestion to use 'Requests' module to keep the connection alive
on a post I created on

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/D0XJPLOLXgo

However, weblogic uses Jython 2.2.1 as standard (even in the latest version). I read up on a post by Maarten Smeets

https://technology.amis.nl/2015/10/04/how-to-use-wlst-as-a-jython-2-7-module/

that allows to deploy weblogic as a Jython 2.7 module. 
So I downloaded & installed Jython 2.7 and import weblogic as a module.

I was able to download, install and import requests as a module, however, I am facing an issue with standard weblogic functionality

```
displayMetricTables('Oracle_BI*','dms_cProcessInfo')
```

that was working earlier without any issues

As per Maarten's post I did try to use prefix **wl.**displayMetricTables, 
but that did not work either

Any and all help will be appreciated

Thanks
P